# How to pattern match even number in the case in scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
def myfunct(n: Int, steps: Int) = n match {
  case 1 =>  steps
  case (x) => if (x % 2 == 0) ...
```

Is there anyway to move the even number matching logic into the case ? Do I need a case class?

Such as:

```
def myfunct(n: Int, steps: Int) = n match {
  case 1 =>  steps
  case (even number??) => ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's called a guard:

```
def myfunct (n: Int, steps: Int) = n match {
  case 1 => steps
  case even if n % 2 == 0 => // stuff
  case odd => // other stuff
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use extractors:

```
object Even {
  def unapply(x: Int) = if (x % 2 == 0) Some(x) else None
}

object Odd {
  def unapply(x: Int) = if (x % 2 == 1) Some(x) else None
}

List(1,2,3,4).foreach { 
  case Even(x) => println(s"$x: even")
  case Odd(x) => println(s"$x: odd")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pattern match on `n` and its `mod`, tupled,

```
def f(n: Int, steps: Int) = (n, n % 2) match {
  case (1, _) => steps
  case (_, 0) => steps + 2
  case _      => steps + 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using Patten Matching guards**

```
def myfunct (n: Int, steps: Int) = n match {
 case 1 =>  steps
 case x if x % 2 == 0 => doSomething
 case x => doSomething
}
```

**Other way is to define `Even` and `Odd` extractors**

```
object One {
  def unapply(n: Int) = if (n == 1) Some(1) else None
}

object Even {
 def unapply(n: Int) = if (n % 2 == 0) Some(n) else None
}

def myfunct (n: Int, steps: Int) = n match {
 case One(x) =>  steps
 case Even(x) => doSomething
 case x => doSomething
}
```

Comment: Even/Odd aren't really doing anything here - there's no connection between`Odd` and the odd-ness of `n`. @VictorMoroz's extractors are the way to do this properly.